# Upper and lower bound given expectation and standard deviation

Tags: probability, random-variables

A random variable $X$ has $E(X) = 10$ and $SD(x) = 4$. Find upper and lower bounds for $P(0 < X < 40)$

My guess is we need to use Chebyshev's inequality. Since we know $X$ must be between 0 and 40, can we first break it up into $P(X>0)$ and $P(X<40)$? How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Lower bound

Since the event in Chebyshev's inequality

$$P(|X-\mu| \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}\tag{*}\label{*}$$

is symmetric about $\mu = E(X) = 10$, so we consider $P(0 < X < 20) \le P(0 < X < 40)$ and try to find a lower bound for this question.  Now we take $\epsilon = 10, \mu = 10, \sigma = 4$ in \eqref{*}.

\begin{aligned}
P(|X - 10| \ge 10) &\le \left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^2 \\
P(X \le 0 \text{ or } X \ge 20) &\le \frac{4}{25} \\
P(0 < X < 20) &= P(|X-10|<10) \\
&= 1-P(|X-10|\ge10) \\
&\ge 1 - \frac{4}{25} = \frac{21}{25}
\end{aligned}

Hence a lower bound would be

$$\frac{21}{25} \le P(0 < X < 20) \le P(0 < X < 40).$$

### Upper bound

*Without* further information about random variable $X$, we can only conclude that $P(0 < X < 40)$ is bounded above by one by definition of probability due to the existence of a random variable which is distributed *near* enough to its mean.

Consider a random variable

$$X = 
\begin{cases}
14 & \text{ with probability } \frac12 \\
6 & \text{ with probability } \frac12
\end{cases}
$$

It's clear that $\mu = E(X) = 10$ and

\begin{align}
\sigma =& \sqrt\frac{(14-10)^2+(6-10)^2}{2} \\
=& \sqrt\frac{4^2 + 4^2}{2} = 4.
\end{align}

So $X$ satisfies the hypothesis of the question.

Therefore, *in this particular case*, $P(0 < X < 40) = 1$.  In other words, *any* number less than one *won't* be an upper bound to the required probability.

### Conclusion

In general, we have $$\frac{21}{25} \le P(0 < X < 40) \le 1.$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would we find an upper bound for $P(X^2 \geq 800)$?, or generally anything that involves the squared random variable

Comment: Do you know anything about it's distribution?  In general, Chebyshev's inequality can only give you a very *rough* bound, since it's proved by Markov's inequality, whose proof relies, again, on a very *rough* estimation.

Comment: @Jayant.M If you know it's distribution function, you may work directly with the definition and separate the positive and negative cases.